# How do I Bind the enum value in MVC3 to select the correct one?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-3, .net-4.0

In ASP.NET MVC3 I think it has got to be a known problem, and I just haven't found the correct answer to my problem.

I have an enum something like this

```
public enum CardType
{
    [Description( "" )]
    None = 0,

    Visa = 1,

    Mastercard = 2,

    Discover = 3,

    [Description( "American Express" )]
    AmericanExpress = 4
}
```

Now the correct term would to be something like this which is being pulled from a table in the database, because I only get certain card types that I have enabled right now.  Which we only have Visa/Mastercard

```
<select name="CardType" id="CardType">
    <option value="1">Visa</option>
    <option value="2">Mastercard</option>
</select>
```

Now lets say I want Mastercard to be defaulted selected.  I have to do something like this

```
CardTypes = new List<SelectListItem>();
var ctypes = db.ExecuteReaderDynamic( "CardType_GetAll", null, System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure )
      .Select( d =>
        new SelectListItem
    {
        Text = d.Name,
        Value = d.ID.ToString()
                    Selected = (d.ID == (int)CardType)
    } );
CardTypes.AddRange( ctypes );
```

Now I don't have a problem with this part, which is not always not promising to work.  Sometimes it will pass "Mastercard" instead of the number value passed...  I am confused on how to fix this...  Only a few solutions which I don't want to use if I can help it because it just means more work...

Answer (score 0):

I'm kinda confused what you are doing with this, I don't really understand.

```
 Selected = (d.ID == (int)CardType)
```

You get the ID and check it against the Enum CardType? Doesn't this give the following error:

```
CardType' is a 'type' but is used like a 'variable'
```

Shouldn't this work?

```
CardTypes = new List<SelectListItem>();
var ctypes = db.ExecuteReaderDynamic( "CardType_GetAll", null, System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure )
      .Select( d =>
        new SelectListItem
    {
        Text = d.Name,
        Value = d.ID.ToString()
                    Selected = false
    } );
CardTypes.AddRange( ctypes );

SelectList oCards = new SelectList(oCardTypes, (int)CardType.Mastercard);
```

And use the oCards directly into your combobox?

Comment: No CardType is a Property in the table, I am just casting it to be an integer.  The problem setting it to Mastercard which is ID 2 in the database for example...  It does not select it choose the first one because its the first option in the select list.  If I submit the data through HttpPost or what not it will set the values according.  This is fustrating as it should work.

Comment: Oh not to mention the way the current Select DropDownList code works is that it attempts to set the selected values.  Basically it does not use my "Select List" that I have done, even doing new SelectList etc. is not working because it expects something like

"MasterCard" as the Value rather than 2, so in theory "2" == "MasterCard" is False...  That is the problem, I am beginning to think I'll have to clone the Select Internal to handle that comparison better where it compares "Enum.ToString" first and if it fails it'll attempt to compare the numeric comparison...

Comment: What's wrong with filling in all the Select values to False default then? The ID matches the Enum index yes? So when you Select the correct one in the SelectList then this should work right? And why are you using the ToString()? You can perfectly push a Int value into the SelectListItem value.